# Can We Install Xamarin Mobile Development Tools in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I am trying to install xamarin tools in visual studio 2012 but whenever i go to this link below
[Xamarin Download Link](https://www.xamarin.com/download)

It comes with xamarin tools for visual studio 2015 . Had microsoft stopped xamarin modile development tools integration in visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here they do still support 2012 https://www.xamarin.com/faq

You can try downloading it here https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dcd5b7bd-48f0-4245-80b6-002d22ea6eee

You can also acces the extension installation from within VS 2012. I believe it will be under tools Menu and then extensions and updates

Comment: check the download link you provide it is same one that i mentioned in my question it downloads xamarin tools installer for vs 2015

Comment: If we go for Extension and Updates Under Tools menu then Search Online for Xamarin it again takes you to xamarin .com / download link and it will download vs 2015 xamarin pack . I think i already mentioned these links in my question